# Is it possible to run a CD deployment without any indexing tools in place?

Tags: indexing

When deploying your application into e.g. Azure there are lots of configurations that allow adding or removing features. A good example would be XP vs XM.

We have the situation where we don't use buckets, we don't use xDB and we don't need shared session - a pretty light setup! What else does Sitecore need behind the scenes that relies on an index?

Is it possible to configure things so that you don't need any search indexes available? The reason being it would save us time during our provisioning and it would save a fair amount of cloud costs.

I seem to recall a conversation that in the future lucene may no longer be supported so I'd rather be able to specify `search:define="None"` rather than something like lucene.

Comment: Sounds like you want XM instead of XP. I assume you don't use EXM and Experience Forms if you don't use xDB? Those need indexes. You can also disable FXM and content testing which need indexes. That would leave you with the Content Editor which I'm pretty sure needs core and master indexes but shouldn't crash if they are not queryable (I haven't tested that though) - but for the CM you can just use Lucene.

Comment: However I don't think its a good idea to have no content indexes as it will lead to bad dev practices - i.e. using sitecore query instead of content search API. Just my 2c though :)

Comment: In 90% of the sites we build we use neither sitecore query or the search api, in favour of simply parsing the tree. Hence the desire to drop indexes where possible. I'm assuming you mean "for the CD you can just use lucene".

Comment: No I mean the content editor needs an index. So cm use lucene and CD won't need anything, but set it up with lucene just to avoid exceptions.